# Why is my SQL query executing indefinitely?

Tags: sql, sql-server

It seems that this code is correct and I am not sure why it is not executing. I thought it might be extremely inefficient but after 15 minutes it is still executing.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.WorkingOrderProducts (OrderID, OrderDate, OrderUnitPrice, ProductName)
    SELECT
        Orders.OrderID, OrderDate, [Order Details].UnitPrice * Quantity AS OrderUnitPrice, ProductName
    FROM 
        dbo.Orders, dbo.[Order Details], dbo.Products
    WHERE
        OrderDate > '1996-12-31'
```

edit: Thank you all for the input.

Comment: How many elements are in `dbo.Orders`? Anyway, one advantage about SQL is that the *base* SQL cannot have deadlocks, so it is guaranteed to finish in a finite amount of time... obviously if you have billion of records in `dbo.Orders` it may take a while for the DB to insert them into a new table, which might have multiple indices etc, but it will end at some point.

Comment: @GACy20: "one advantage about SQL is that the base SQL cannot have deadlocks, so it is guaranteed to finish in a finite amount of time" - not true. An open transaction on another connection could prevent

Comment: `FROM dbo.Orders, dbo.[Order Details], dbo.Products WHERE OrderDate > '1996-12-31'` You are doing a `CARTESIAN JOIN`

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s . . . Not only is the use discouraged, but if the OP has used `JOIN`, the OP would not have had this problem -- either the OP would have remembered the `JOIN` condition or SQL Server would have reported an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using implicit `CROSS JOIN` in your query and this can kill your performance if you don't data merged like this.

Let's say that the Orders table has 100 records, then Order Details have 100, and Products have 100.

The number of produced rows in the result will be 1 million because it is cartesian product.

You might think of rewriting your query and adding more clauses in your where condition.

Comment: `adding more clauses in your where condition` Please don't. You should use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I agree with @Squirrel you should avoid using CROSS JOIN if you don't really need it. However, sometimes you have to write statements with CROSS JOIN, and that the only solution.

Comment: I am not saying to avoid cross join, use `JOIN` instead of just comma. Should be `FROM Orders JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.Id = [Order Details].Id JOIN Products ON Products.Id = [Order Details].ProductId` . See the link posted by marc_s